# How do I properly work with unicode characters in python to keep from getting errors?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii

I'm working on a python plugin for Google Quick Search Box, and it's doing some odd things with non-ascii characters. It seems like the code works fine up until I try constructing a string containing the non-ascii characters (ü has been my test character). I am using the following code snippet for the construction, with new_task as the variable that is being input from GQSB.

```
the_sig = ("%sapi_key%sauth_token%smethod%sname%sparse%stimeline%s" %
           (api_secret, api_key, the_token, method, new_task, doParse, timeline))
```

It's giving me this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I am understanding correctly, this is because I am trying to string together a unicode character inside an ascii string. Everything I could find told me to declare the encoding at the top with this:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
```

Which I have. And when I pull the code snippet that constructs the string into a new script, it works just fine. But for some reason, int he context of the rest of the code, it fails, every time. The only thing I can think of is that it is because it's inside it's own class, but that doesn't make any sense to me.

The full code can be found on GitHub [here](http://github.com/gfontenot/RTM_QSB/blob/master/Send_To_RTM.py)

Thanks in advance for any help. I am stumped on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you should do to fix this.

1. Convert all string literal that contain non-ASCII characters to Unicode literals. Example: `u'über'`.
2. Do intermediate processing on Unicode. In other words, if you receive an encoded string (no matter the encoding), decode it to Unicode before working on it. Example:

   ```
   s = utf8_string.decode('utf8') + latin1_string.decode('latin1')
   ```
3. When outputting the string or sending it somewhere, encode it with an encoding that your receiver understands. Example: `send(s.encode('utf8'))`.

Complete example:

```
input1 = get_possibly_nonascii_input().decode('iso-8859-1')
input2 = get_possibly_nonascii_input().decode('iso-8859-1')
input3 = u'üvw'

s =  u'%s -> %s' % (input3, (input1 + input2).upper())

send_output(s.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. I had to decode, then reencode to utf 8 to send it to hashlib. Thanks a lot. It looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using Python 2.x.

The file encoding declaration specifies how string *literals* are read by the interpreter.

You should handle all strings as `unicode` values, not `str` ones. If you read a `str` from the outside world, you should decode it to `unicode` explicitely. The same applies to outputting strings.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
u_dia_str = '\xc3\xbc'   # str
lambda_unicode = u'λ'    # unicode

# input value
u_dia = u_dia_str.decode('utf-8')

sig_unicode = u'%s%s' % (u_dia, lambda_unicode)
# => u'üλ'

# output value
sig_str = sig_unicode.encode('utf-8')
# => '\xc3\xbc\xce\xbb'
```

Comment: Ok, I decode the input as utf-8, and now I can get past that part. But immediately after that, I encode the string as an md5 hash with this:

    hashed_sig = hashlib.md5(the_sig).hexdigest()

And now  I get the same ascii codec error as before. Is this a limitation of hashlib? Or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I didn;t realize that I had to re-encode. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit beyond my expertise, but I think `# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-` at the top declares the text encoding that your Python source file is saved in.

Is it really saved in iso-8859-15?